# How to create dynamic table name based on date and time?

Tags: python, mysql, string

I am going to create dynamic table name based on the date time function in MySQL using Python. I would like to use *datetime* function,to name the tables, when I run my code. however, it does not work.
Please see below my code:

```
tablename=str(datetime())
mycursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {text}(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(50))'.format(text=tablename))
```

I am not able to use *str* function to change the format to string.
When I use the following code, a table called datetime() will be created, however, the table name will not be dynamic anymore and this is not what I am looking for.

```
tablename="datetime()"
    mycursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {text}(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(50))'.format(text=tablename))
```

Comment: ```from datetime import date``` then ```mycursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{text}`(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(50))'.format(text=date.today()))```

Comment: Consider using [_PARTITIONing_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) instead